# Encoding Extreme #3

Tags: cipher

While I was writing on a file on my Linux portable computer, the thing I was writing suddenly started to change!

Take a look at the file:

```
¶€µ€µ”€¶ ŧø ðø ænøŧħ€¶ @€n¢øð→nŋ €»ŧ¶€µ€@ đø¶ ŧøðæ←|
```

What happened to my computer or what did I do to "encode" the text?

And, what's written on the file?

(I didn't found any help on Google.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were holding one of the “alternate graphics” keys on your Canadian Multilingual Standard keyboard:

[image]

Note how the dark green glyph on the ‘R’ key is ¶, etc.

Only ‘E’ is different; I guess that one is vendor-specific or something.

Comment: Oh, Canada. That didn't occur to me - nice one! This also doesn't explain the punctuation.

Comment: I suspect it’s really some spin-off of this layout we’re dealing with, or vice versa. I don’t exactly feel like tracking down which one.

Answer (score 6):

It's a simple substitution cipher where (most of) the symbols resemble the corresponding letter

> Examples:
>  € = E, ¢ = C, ŧ = T, ¶ = R

It appears to say

> REMEMBER TO DO ANOTHER "ENCODING EXTREME" FOR TODAY.

Comment: is it his PC or his pet dog?

Comment: @manshu It was an untrained møøse.